# JavaScript return value: What does <> mean?

Tags: javascript, vline

I am trying to use the API in [this page](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Channel).

The definition is like this below:

```
vline.Promise.<vline.Collection> getMessages([Number opt_limit])
```

I want to use the return value of this API, however I don't understand what the `<>` means. I have researched about the JavaScript language but I couldn't find any clues.

My script is:

```
vlinesession.getPerson(userId).done(function(person) {       
    person.postMessage(msg); //it works.
    var log = person.getMessages(20); //how can I parse 'log'?
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint or some samples on how to use this API?

Comment: not so much a problem with Javascript, as a problem with documentation.

Comment: It's not standard Javascript, I'd guess it's supposed to resemble the syntax of generics in other languages. So a `Promise<Foo>` is a promise that "returns" a `Foo` - most likely passes it to its completion handler, since CPS is common in JS. I'm guessing you "parse" log by doing `log.done(function(messages) { ... });` where `messages` will be a `Collection` of messages. (Whatever `Collection` is, look up the documentation for it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cbuckley is correct in his description, but I want to expand on it and give an example.

```
vline.Promise.<vline.Collection> getMessages([Number opt_limit])
```

This indicates that it is returning a [`vline.Promise`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Promise) with the result to the success callback being of type [`vline.Collection`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Collection).

Here's an example:

```
vlinesession.getPerson(userId).done(function(person) {       
    person.getMessages().done(function(msgCollection) {   // msgCollection is a vline.Collection of vline.Message's
        for (var i = 0; i < msgCollection.getSize(); i++) {
            var msg = msgCollection.getAt(i);       // this is the vline.Message
            console.log('Message from: ' + msg.getSender() + 
                        ' with body: ' + msg.getBody());
        }
    }); 
});
```

Note that I left out the [`fail`](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Promise#fail) handlers for brevity, but you should include those as well to make your code robust.

Comment: Thankss @tom ,I have tried this codes,but it says "Object [object Object] has no method 'getAt'" ,while msgCollection.getSize() returns correct value(20) though,,

Comment: @whitebear, sorry this is a bug on our end. I'll post an update when it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks @tom. I would appreciate your quick response.

Comment: THanks !,getAt() works!,but somehow every messages are 'Hello there'

Answer (score 6):

This is explained on the [`vline.Promise` documentation page](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.Promise):

> In the documentation, you will frequently see functions with a return value of the form `vline.Promise.<foo.Bar>`. This is a short-hand way of saying that the function returns a `Promise` and the result provided to success callbacks on that `Promise` will be of type `foo.Bar`. We may refer to this less formally as a "promise of a foo.Bar".

Answer (score 0):

`<vline.Collection>` should be replaced with something else, it's not javascript syntax.